# Python Chatbot Math Functions

Tags: python, math, chatbot

I'm making a chatbot with Python. How could I teach my chatbot to do math for the person it is talking to? Would there be a way for me to make it use Python math functions (i.e. 3 * 8)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its very easy to do maths,

**Multiplication** :

```
input_0 = input("What is the first number you want to multiply")
input_1 = input("What is the second number you want to multiply")

answer = int(input_0) * int(input_1)

print(answer)
```

**Division** :

```
input_0 = input("What is the first number you want to divide")
input_1 = input("What is the second number you want to divide")

answer = int(input_0) / int(input_1)

print(answer)
```

**Addition** :

```
input_0 = input("What is the first number you want to add")
input_1 = input("What is the second number you want to add")

answer = int(input_0) + int(input_1)

print(answer)
```

**Subtraction** :

```
input_0 = input("What is the first number you want to subtract")
input_1 = input("What is the second number you want to subtract")

answer = int(input_0) - int(input_1)

print(answer)
```